# How can I combine two columns together to get a result based only if they equal these columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I join two columns together to then filter by the combined column? One column is the parent and one column is the quantity, I then search for the result based only if the column quantity is from the bomparent and not equaling the bom child.

Can I combine the result somehow or is there another way to get the quantity only for the bomparent??

If I try:

```
select concat(bom.bomparent, bom.bomqty) As bpqty

from bom
```

This returns the part and quantity together - 00098101x1

So I can't filter using this result.

If I try:

```
select bom.bomparent, bom.bomqty

from bom

where bomqty ='1'
AND bomqty != bom.bomchild
```

I get error: Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

The data types are: bom.parent - nvarchar, bom.qty - float

If I try to convert nvarchar to float I get an error:

```
select 

CAST([bomparent] AS varchar) AS bomparent, bomqty

from bom

where bomqty ='1'
AND bomqty != bom.bomchild
```

Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

Comment: share sample data and result

Comment: As per the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), help us help you and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data and desired results.

Comment: provide a [mre] for your problem ideally as dbfiddle

Comment: How do I share from SQL Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You have asked too many things and not made your question clear but from what i gather you are trying to solve this error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

This error is because of your where clause as you are comparing `bomqty(float)` with `'1'(nvarchar)`.

This is how you should do it

```
select 

bomparent, bomqty

from bom

where bomqty = 1 AND bomqty != bom.bomchild 
--Also make sure bomqty is of same type as bomchild
```

I am not sure if you will get your desired results as you haven't make that clear and it depends on your logic. but this will resolve your issue